# Regarding C# OOPS virtual/override keyword usage

Tags: c#, oop

just see this program

```
class A
        {
              public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("A::Foo()"); }
        }

        class B : A
        {
              public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("B::Foo()"); }
        }

        class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                A a;
                B b;

                a = new A();
                b = new B();
                a.Foo();  // output --> "A::Foo()"
                b.Foo();  // output --> "B::Foo()"

                a = new B();
                a.Foo();  // output --> "A::Foo()"
            }
        }
```

1) how to class can have function having same name. class A has foo() function and class b has foo() function when class b entend A. when class b extend a then by inheritance class b got the function called foo(). why the above code run without any error ?

2)

```
        a = new B();
        a.Foo();  // output --> "A::Foo()"
```

what is the meaning of a=new B() ?

are we creating instance of B if yes then when we write a.Foo() then foo() function of class b should call but  foo() function of class a is getting called why ??

when we add virtual/override keyword then foo() function of class b is getting called.

```
class A
        {
            public virtual void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("A::Foo()"); }
        }

        class B : A
        {
            public override void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("B::Foo()"); }
        }

        class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                A a;
                B b;

                a = new A();
                b = new B();
                a.Foo();  // output --> "A::Foo()"
                b.Foo();  // output --> "B::Foo()"

                a = new B();
                a.Foo();  // output --> "B::Foo()"
            }
        }
```

so please explain some one what is going on behind the scene. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, `B.Foo` *overrides* `A.Foo`, which means that the method's logic is being *replaced*.

In your first example though, `B.Foo` is *hiding* `A.Foo`'s implementation. There is no inheritance involved.
So if a variable of type A contains an instance of type B (i.e., `A a = new B();`), A's implementation will be used instead.

---

> we can directly create instance of b and call foo() but why people
>   write this kind of code A a=new B() and then call a.foo() ? what kind
>   of objective can be achieve writing this kind of code. thanks

Instead of asking why would you write `A a=new B()`, ask yourself: why would you want to use a `new` method?

One of the reasons might be to overcome the fact that you can't override `A.Foo`, because it wasn't marked as virtual.
Say you're given a class `A`, implemented in a third-party assembly that you cannot modify.
If you extend that class with your own class `B`, then you *hide* its implementation with a `new` method, and write `B b = new B(); b.Foo();`

Comment: we can directly create instance of b and call foo() but why people write this kind of code A a=new B() and then call a.foo() ? what kind of objective can be achieve writing this kind of code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> when class b extend a then by inheritance class b got the function called foo(). why the above code run without any error ?

Because the member in `B` is simply *hiding* the member in `A`.

> what is the meaning of a=new B() ?

Since `B` implements `A`, you're creating an instance of `B` and typing it as `A` when you use it everywhere else. That's why the function in class `A` is getting called instead of `B`.

> when we add virtual/override keyword then foo() function of class b is getting called.

The reason `B` is getting called here is because it is in fact *overriding* the functionality of `A`.

Comment: u said : Because the member in B is simply hiding the member in A. i guess we use new keyword for hiding but in that above program new keyword never use. so how program execute properly?

Comment: @Thomas, the `new` keyword is not *necessary* for hiding. It just makes it *explicit.*

Comment: we can directly create instance of b and call foo() but why people write this kind of code A a=new B() and then call a.foo() ? what kind of objective can be achieve writing this kind of code. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, I'm not sure on that one friend. I don't think I'd generally write this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a method with the same name it hides the method.

If you want to call the inherited method, you can do this:

```
var b = new B();

var casted = (A)b;

casted.Foo(); // will call A.Foo
```

If your intention is to overwrite the functionality of `Foo` in `B` then you can use the `new` keyword within `B`:

```
public new void Foo() { ... }
```

Or use `virtual` and `override` as you stated.

Comment: we can directly create instance of b and call foo() but why people write this kind of code A a=new B() and then call a.foo() ? what kind of objective can be achieve writing this kind of code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> why the above code run without any error ?

It produces a warning: `'B.Foo()' hides inherited member 'A.Foo()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

So the compiler warns you about a potential error, but it's valid and the `B.Foo` methods hides the `A.Foo` one.

> are we creating instance of B if yes then when we write a.Foo() then
>   foo() function of class b should call but foo() function of class a is
>   getting called why ??

You are calling `Foo` on a `A` variable. So even if this `A` instance is actually of type B, you're calling a method on a variable of type `A`.

Comment: we can directly create instance of b and call foo() but why people write this kind of code A a=new B() and then call a.foo() ? what kind of objective can be achieve writing this kind of code. thanks